# Launching applications using python

Tags: python

I wanted to launch an application like CANalyzer.exe using python, without using the path of the application. I am trying to launch the application using COM interface. I got the code to open excel files which is win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") which worked but it doesnt work if i mention any other application name. Please help me with the code.

Comment: Why don't you want to specify the path of the application?

Comment: its a part of requirement not to use the path

Answer (score 1):

Use `subprocess.call` or `os.system`.

Comment: How would it help out?